# SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT ignored on Jackson 2.6.5

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson mapper version 2.6.5 with Spring Boot but I can seem to get `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` to work. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/jackson-create-json.jsp). My code is as follows.

```
public class SerializationExampleTreeModel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create the node factory that gives us nodes.
        JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory(false);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        // create a json factory to write the treenode as json. for the example
        // we just write to console
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator generator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(stringWriter);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        // the root node - album
        JsonNode album = nodeFactory.objectNode();

        album.put("Album-Title", "Kind Of Blue")

        ArrayNode songs = nodeFactory.arrayNode()
        songs.add("Song8").add("Song2")

        album.put("Songs", songs)

        ObjectNode artist = nodeFactory.objectNode()
        artist.put("Name", "Alex" )

        album.put( "artist", artist)


        mapper.writeTree(generator, album)

        println stringWriter.toString()


    }

}
```

I always get the result:

`{"Album-Title":"Kind Of Blue","Songs":["Song8","Song2"],"artist":{"Name":"Alex"}}` whether I include the line `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)` or not. What is going on?

Note: I'm compiling my code using `groovyc` and semi-colons aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `StringWriter` to write the output and it ignores the formatting you set on `ObjectMapper` as expected. Instead, use:

```
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(album));
```

If you prefer to use as you are using, you can declare the printer like this before writing the tree:

```
generator.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
mapper.writeTree(generator, album);
```

This will allow the correct output with:

```
stringWriter.toString()
```